# How can I copy a selection of files from multiple folders into multiple folders?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, android

I am developing an Android-app in OS X, and want to use some third-party icons. I have downloaded and extracted the icons into this folder structure:

- drawable-mdpi

  - ic_icon1.png
  - ...
- drawable-hdpi

  - ic_icon1.png
  - ...
- drawable-xhdpi

  - ic_icon1.png
  - ...
- drawable-xxhdpi

  - ic_icon1.png
  - ...

I want to copy the files named ic_icon1.png from each directory into my own folder structure with the same folders, ignoring the rest of the icons in the source folders. How can I accomplish this using Finder or Terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gcp` from [homebrew](http://brew.sh) for this. Install `gcp` with

```
brew install coreutils
```

Then You can make something like this:

```
gcp --parents drawable*/ic_icon1.png /path/to/output/dir
```

This will copy all `ic_icon1.png` preserving directory tree.

From `man gcp`:

> ```
>    --parents
>           use full source file name under DIRECTORY
> ```

Comment: Is it possible to copy all files from each folder into a single destination folder?

Comment: @Keyslinger maybe something like `find . -type f -exec cp {} /path/to/dest/dir/ \;`